# Return Action as result of another action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I was facing a problem when I try to return an Action from another Action.
I got something like this:

```
public ActionResult Action (int param1, string param2)
{
    ActionViewModel vm = new ActionViewModel();
    vm.Param1Prop = param1;
    vm.Param2Prop = param2;

    return View(vm);
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Action (ActionViewModel vm)
{
    //Do Something...

    if (vm.DoItAgain)
    {
        return Action(vm.Param1Prop-1, vm.Param2Prop);
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

When the line `return Action(vm.Param1Prop-1, vm.ParamProp);` goes to `Action(int param1, string param2)`, executes and everything looks like go well. But don't. The render result looks like `return View(vm)` was executed instead, all the values of the `vm` are the same as sended in the Post Action, not the ones i'm passing on `return Action(vm.Param1Prop-1, vm.ParamProp);`.

I'm not sure why isn't working, the ActionResult returning is being ignored? The code inside the first Action method executes fine (I debug and put a log inside to check it) and the return of the first method is the end of the response so why it looks like that line never happened?
I also try to modify the vm on the PostAction to see if the vm was being infered somehow. That don't work either.
To make that work, I put a RedirectToAction instead of using the return Action:
`RedirectToAction("Action", new { param1 = vm.Param1Prop-1, param2 = vm.Param2Prop });` and everything work fine. I completly understand why RedirectToAction works, but i cannot figure out why invoke the Action method don't. 
Anyone can enlighten me about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are probably seeing is the `ModelState` values from the original POST. These will take precedence over the ones you return to your view. You can rectify this by clearing the values from `ModelState`. However, you shouldn't need to.

You shouldn't return one action from another. You should return a *redirect* to that action:

```
return RedirectToAction("Action",
       new { param1 = vm.Param1Prop-1, param2 = vm.Param2Prop });
```

Because you've performed a proper redirect now instead of just returning the result of the GET action directly from the POST, `ModelState` will have been cleared when the original request ended and you won't see your old posted values.

Comment: You're right. The ModelState wasn't clear and match the results I get, but why the ModelState wasn't override or update with the values that I set on the GET Action? I guess that the context and routevalues are from the POST Action because there isn't a request invoking the method, but I'm not sure. BTW I agree that the proper method is a Redirection instead on invoking an Action method, is a way to ensure that the life cycle is correct, but I wonder why the "alternate" way don't work. Well, I know why don't work, because the ModelState as you said, but I'm not sure why ModelState don't update

Comment: When you use editor/display templates, the framework looks in a number of places to try and populate the values. The *model* is just one of those - `ModelState` is another (mainly for the purposes of redisplaying forms with entered values and validation messages). `ModelState` has always taken precedence. So if you don't want the `ModelState` values to be used, you need to clear them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.clear(v=vs.118).aspx.

Comment: Bear in mind also that when you return another action explicitly, it is *still* a POST action (the same POST action as when the form was posted). In your example, you are invoking an action that is intended for GET during a POST.